# Convert anonymous type list to normal list

Tags: c#

I have a simple model like:

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    public Guid Value1 { get; set; }
    public Guid Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have anonymousTypeList like:

```
var parameterstest = assignNotificationTableType
                       .Select(x => new { TaskId, x.EmpGuid })
                       .ToList();
```

So I want to convert that anonymous type list to a normal list so I try:

```
List<MyDataClass> lista = new List<MyDataClass>();
foreach(var i in parameterstest)
{
    lista.Add(i.TaskId,i.EmpGuid);
}
```

But I get

> Error CS1501  No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments

Comment: `lista.Add(new MyDataClass { Value1 = i.TaskId, Value2 = i.EmpGuid });`

Comment: You are calling the `Add` method on a `List<MyDataClass>`. The `Add` method adds a new item to the list, so it expects an object of type `MyDataClass` to be passed to it. So what you need to do is first construct a new `MyDataClass` object: `MyDataClass myDataClass = new MyDataClass();`, then set it's properties: `myDataClass.Value1 = i.TaskId; myDataClass.Value2 = i.EmpGuid;`, and then pass this object to the method: `lista.Add(myDataClass);`

Comment: Anonymous types aren't really special in .NET. The c# compiler just does some magic to basically automatically create a hidden class that matches the properties. Anywhere you use an anonymous type, you can always use a regularly declared class.

Answer (score 9):

You can use it simply:

```
var parameterstest = assignNotificationTableType
                   .Select(x => new MyDataClass { Value1 = TaskId, Value2 = x.EmpGuid })
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen its hard to tell. there could be a property or field that is being used here.